# Is finiteness necessary in this exercise?

Tags: group-theory

This is from Dummit&Foote Abstract Algebra Chap 3.1 Problem 28.

Here is problem & solution of this problem.

Let $N$ be finite subgroup of $G$ and suppose $G=\langle T\rangle$ and $N=\langle S\rangle$ for some subsets $S$ and $T$ of $G$. Prove $N$ is normal in $G$ iff $tSt^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $t \in T$.

https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/a-criterion-for-finite-subgroup-normalcy-on-generating-sets-of-the-subgroup-and-group/

Finiteness of $N$ is used as: $tNt^{-1}=N$ from $tNt^{-1} \subseteq N$.

If $N$ is infinite, then $G$ is infinite, so $t^{-1}$ is not always expressed as finite product of elements of $T$. So we can't get $t^{-1}Nt\subseteq N$ from $tNt^{-1} \subseteq N$.

So we can't avoid line 
$tNt^{-1}=N$ from $tNt^{-1} \subseteq N$. without finiteness of $N$.

I think finiteness of $N$ is crucial in this proof, so I think there is counterexample of this excercise without finiteness.

Also hardness of taking counterexample is making $T$ s.t. $\langle T\rangle=G$. But, it should be $T \neq G$ because it implies normalness.

I'm trouble to taking non abelian group $G$ and $T\neq G$ s.t. $\langle T\rangle=G$.

Can you find counterexample of this excercise or is that still true for without finiteness of $N$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's just example for single element of $T$, it does not hold for all $T$ since $N$ is not normal.

Comment: Indeed. I deleted the comment as soon as I posted it, as I realized that.

Comment: (Though the same ideas can be used to provide an example by picking things suitably).

Comment: Pardon me, if I am restating a comment that seems to have been previously deleted, but if $t^{-1}\in G$ and $G=<T>$ then $t^{-1}$ (like any other element of $G$) is a finite product of elements of $T$ so that you get $t^{-1}Nt\subseteq N$ from the fact that for any $t'\in T$, $t'N(t')^{-1}\subseteq N$.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin No, it will be a finite product of elements from $T$ and their inverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary.

**Hint**: Consider $G={\bf Z}_2^{\bf Z}\rtimes {\bf Z}$ with the natural action (so that $k\cdot(a_i)_{i\in {\bf Z}}=(a_{i+k})_{i\in {\bf Z}}$) and the subgroup of sequences with positive support.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked many times before. The standard counterexample is the group defined  by the presntation $\langle x,y \mid yxy^{-1} =x^2 \rangle$ with $T=\{ x,y \}$, $S =\{ x \}$. It can also  be defined as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Q})$.

Comment: If it has been asked many times before and you know it, you should vote to close as duplicate.